# Dynamic scoping

Tags: dynamic, scoping

When using dynamic scoping first output is obviously 10.

I am curious about second output. Is it hello or 30.5 and why?

```
void main() {
  f1(); 
  f2();  
} 

void f1() { 
  int x = 10; 
  g();
}

void f2() {
  String x = "hello";
  f3(); 
  g(); 
}

void f3() {
  double x = 30.5;
}

void g() { 
  print(x)
}
```

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: excuse me for using void. problem is not language specific, generally on dynamic scoping concept.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic scoping means that x refers to the x declared in the most recent frame of the call-stack the has one.

so since the most recent call before g() is f3() so answer is 30.5 and not hello.